# Jquery dropdown and grid with template not working in IE9

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, jquery-templates

I have tested alot. Code is working fine in FIREFOX 5 but same code not working in IE9.

*Below is the code which is not working in IE9 at all for DROPDOWN and GRID. When I clear IE cache and refresh page than grid
is filled with new values. I see AJAX calls fine.*

**PROBLEM IE9 :**

*Drop down refill code not working in IE9. JQuery function to refill dropdown is in JS file.*

```
var ReloadMenu = (function () {
    $.getJSON("/HeaderMenu/GetHeaderMenu", function (data) {
        $('#headermenuDd >option').remove();
        $("#headermenuDd").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'></option>");

        var text = $.trim($("#dropdowntext").val());
        var options = $("#headermenuDd");
        $.each(data, function () {
            if (text == this.Id)
                options.append($("<option class=\"green\"></option>").val(this.Id).text(this.DisplayName));
            else
                options.append($("<option></option>").val(this.Id).text(this.DisplayName));
        });
    });
});
```

*Grid refill code not working in IE9. JQuery function to refill grid is in JS file.*

```
var ReloadGrid = (function () {
    $.getJSON("/HeaderMenu/GetHeaderGrid", function (data) {
        $('table.gridTable > tbody').empty();
        (data.length <= 0) ? $("#gridBtn").hide() : $("#gridBtn").show();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { data[i].num = i + 1; }
        $('#gridTemplate').tmpl(data).appendTo('table.gridTable > tbody');
    });
});
```

*Code is in csxhtml mvc3 file for making  GRID.*

```
<script id="gridTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr class="gridRow">
        <td class="cellTd ">
            <input type="checkbox" id="deleteCb" />
            <input type="hidden" id="Id_ + ${num}" class="idField" value="${Id}" />
        </td>
        <td class="cellTd">
            <input id="index" name="index" class="numberField" type="text" value="${IndexOrder}" />
        </td>
        <td class="cellTd">${DisplayName}</td>
        <td class="cellTd ">${UrlName}</td>
        <td class="cellTd ">
            <input type="checkbox" id="activeCb" {{if Active}} checked{{/if}} />
        </td>
    </tr>

</script>
<table class="gridTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead>
        <tr class="gridTitleRow">
            <td class="iconLink width36">Delete</td>
            <td class="iconLink width60">Sort Order</td>
            <td class="iconLink widthAuto">Display Name</td>
            <td class="iconLink widthAuto">Url Name</td>
            <td class="iconLink widthAuto">Active</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GET requests could be cached by some browsers. Try disabling cache and instead of [`$.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and set the `cache: false` parameter:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/HeaderMenu/GetHeaderGrid', // TODO: never hardcode urls like this use Url helpers
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        // same as before
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks code is working fine now. Onething, How to use URL helper to replace hardcoded URL?

Comment: @pirzada, like this: `@Url.Action("GetHeaderGrid", "HeaderMenu")`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/HeaderMenu/GetHeaderGrid', // TODO: never hardcode urls like this use Url helpers
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        // same as before
    }
});
```